# Keep leading zeros from a kronos export

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am exporting some data on a flat file from an application to a sharefile into a `.csv` file. The leading zeros get dropped after the export. I'am trying to find a way to keep the leading zeros after on the `.csv` file after the export.

[image]

**File that is export from the source with kronos**

[image]

Result of the export in a sharefile on `.csv` with the missing leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Excel interprets the values as numbers and will remove leading zeroes. If you want to keep the leading zeroes in Excel, the data needs to be text in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

As teylyn answered, the dropping of leading zeros is just Excel interpreting the values as numbers. you should be able to verify this by opening the file in Notepad etc, the full ID's should appear.

Depending on what you're using the the csv data in Excel for, there's couple of workarounds, assuming you can't change the output format to wrap the ID's in double quotes.

If you're just using Excel to view/verify the data then there's no problem, just don't save it when you close the file in Excel.

If you're doing other things in the csv file and then saving it as an xlsx file, then you *can* use a formula to 'fix' the ID's. In say E2 put `=REPT("0",6-LEN(A2))&A2` which will in effect pad out the ID's to 6 characters long with leading zeros. You can then copy/paste the values into column A and delete column E then save.

If you're playing around with the data in Excel then Power Query is probably a better bet than adding formulas/replacing values etc.

Comment: What if I have 10 files with over a hundred records. It is for payroll.

Comment: What are you actually doing with the Kronos export csv’s?